# How to combine two SQL queries in one

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have tables *user*, *participant* and *chat*. I need to get all users in a specific chat and amount of chats that user in by chat name. For example current tables:

```
  user      chat          participant
id|name   id|name       user_id|chat_id
1|Mike    1|School            1|1
2|John    2|Football          2|1
3|Sara    3|Gym               1|2
                              3|3
```

And by keyword "School" I want to get this

```
Mike|2
John|1
```

I have two queries to get first and second column in result but don't know how to combine it:

```
SELECT user.name FROM user 
JOIN participant ON (user.id = participant.user_id) 
JOIN chat ON (participant.chat_id = chat.id) WHERE chat.name = 'School';
```

That gives me

```
Mike
John
```

And

```
SELECT user.name, COUNT(*) FROM user 
JOIN participant ON (user.id = participant.user_id) GROUP BY user.name;
```

returns

```
John|1
Mike|2
Sara|1
```

So how to combine it?

Comment: what final output you want ?

Comment: pls give the desired output

Comment: @Mr.Bhosale "And by keyword "School" I want to get this"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TRY THIS**

```
SELECT p1.name, COUNT(p.user_id) totUser
FROM participant p 
INNER JOIN (select u.id, u.name FROM participant p 
    inner JOIN chat c ON c.id = p.[chat_id]
    INNER JOIN user u ON u.id = p.user_id
    AND c.name = 'School') p1 ON p1.id = p.user_id
GROUP BY p1.name
```

Comment: "Error: near "#participant": syntax error", but without "#" works fine, thanks!

Comment: It should be corrected, I have used temporary table for testing purpose, Thanks for knowing me.

Answer (score 1):

using Subquery  and joins :

```
            select u.name,count(p.chat_id) as 'Count' from user u
            inner join participant p on p.user_id = u.id
            where 
            p.user_id  in ( select user_id from participant pp inner join chat cc on cc.id = pp.chat_id  where 
            cc.name = 'School' )    
            group by u.name
            order by Count desc
```

> Output :

[image]